# React JS. How can I display the image inside the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, map-function, react-functional-component

How can I display the image inside the object in React.js?

```
const Area = () =>{ 
 const flags = [
    { id: 1, name: "USA", image: "./us.png" },
    { id: 2, name: "Canada", image: "./ca.png" },
  ];

return (
    <div>
      {flags.map((area) => {
        return <img key={area.id} src={area.image} />;
      })}
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing ? The above code looks good and should work

Comment: Please double check the path of the image. Image path might be a problem else it is looking fine.

Comment: This is not a good way to reference a local image in react js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use require for images inside an object.But your code works fine even without that you just have to return it inside return method().

```
  const Area = () =>{ 
  const flags = [
    { id: 1, name: "USA", image: require('./us.png') },
    { id: 2, name: "Canada", image: require('./ca.png') },
   ]

  return (
      <div>
          {flags.map((area) => 
          <img key={area.id} src={area.image} />
    )}
     </div>
   )
   }
   return(
   Area()
   )
```

It works fine this way as well

```
const Area = () =>{ 
const flags = [
  { id: 1, name: "USA", image: "./us.png" },
  { id: 2, name: "Canada", image: "./ca.png" },
]

return (
  <div>
    {flags.map((area) => 
     <img key={area.id} src={area.image} />
    )}
  </div>
 )
}
return(
Area()
 )
```

Comment: it was the "require" keyword that made it work. thx

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing that you need to do is wrap the src in `{}` which you're doing already.

Then if you're using **webpack**. Instead of : `<img src={"./us.png"} />`

You need to use `require()` like this `<img src={require('./us.png')} />`

```
 const Area = () => {
  const flags = [
    { id: 1, name: "USA", image: "./us.png" },
    { id: 2, name: "Canada", image: "./ca.png" },
  ]

return (
  <div>
    {flags.map((area) => {
      return <img key={area.id} src={require(area.image)} />;
    })}
  </div>
 )}
}
```

Another option would be to first import the image as shown below

`import ca from './us.png'`  or  `const us = require('./us.png)`.

Then add them to your `flags` object like shown below:

```
import usa from './us.png;
import canada from './ca.png;

const Area = () => {
  const flags = [
   { id: 1, name: "USA", image: usa },
   { id: 2, name: "Canada", image: canada },
  ]

return (
   <div>
     {flags.map((area) => {
       return <img key={area.id} src={area.image} />;
     })}
   </div>
  )}
}
```

Comment: It works if I add the word "require" inside the object  or if I import the image and then use it.  Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comments that please double check the path of the image. Image path might be a problem else it is looking fine. Moreover, you can press ctrl+click on path to route to that folder or check it manually.